# Accessing the contents of a buffer

Tags: c, malloc, buffer

```
*arrayInts = 42;

arrayInts[0] = 42;
```

Is something like that equal logically?
I don't quite understand how buffers work so I am unsure about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're logically equivalent.

`a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`. In this case, that means `arrayInts[0]` is equivalent to `*(arrayInts+0)`, which is obviously equivalent to `*(arrayInts)`, which is equivalent to `*arrayInts`.

For what little it's worth, that means that `0[arrayInts]` is also equivalent. This is frequently seen in obfuscated code in the form of things like `i["abcd"]`.